# App parar de funcionar após push notification com firebase no ionic 3

Tags: ionic, apache-cordova, firebase, push-notification, ionic3

Estou tentando fazer um `push notification` usando o `cloudSettings` com firebase, porém quando envio uma mensagem o app para de funcionar e aparece a seguinte mensagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

app.module.ts:

```
const cloudSettings: CloudSettings = {
  'core': {
    'app_id': 'APP_ID',
  },
  'push': {
    'sender_id': 'SENDER_ID',
    'pluginConfig': {
      'ios': {
        'badge': true,
        'sound': true
      },
      'android': {
        'iconColor': '#343434'
      }
    }
  }
};
...
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    CloudModule.forRoot(cloudSettings)
]
...
```

app.component.ts:

```
....
initialize(){
 this.registerDeviceToken();
 this.handlerNotifications();
}

registerDeviceToken() {
    this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
      return this.push.saveToken(t);
    }).then((t: PushToken) => {
      console.log('Token saved: ', t.token);
    });
  }

handlerNotifications() {
    this.push.rx.notification()
      .subscribe((msg) => {
        alert(msg.title + ': ' + msg.text);
     });
}
```

No meu package.json a lib está definida da seguinte forma:

```
"phonegap-plugin-push": {
                "SENDER_ID": "SENDER_ID",
                "variables": "[object Object]"
}
```

E no config.xml:

```
<plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="^2.0.0">
        <variable name="SENDER_ID" value="SENDER_ID" />
        <variable name="variables" value="[object Object]" />
</plugin>
```

**Ionic info:**

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.0.1
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.0
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.10.3
OS                : Linux 3.13
npm               : 3.10.10
```

Log do erro:

> 09-06 15:09:51.634  2829 22829 I ActivityManager: Start proc
>   19365:br.com.app/u0a138 for activity br.com.app/.MainActivity 09-06
>   15:09:51.675 19365 19365 W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown
>   path: /data/app/br.com.app-1/lib/arm 09-06 15:09:51.709 19365 19365 I
>   FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app br.com.app
>   09-06 15:09:52.024   637   637 D SFPerfTracer:        layers: (5:8)
>   (StatusBar (0xa987ec00): 20:31344)
>   (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (0xa9d49400): 20:20506) (Sprite
>   (0xa987b000): 0:34)* (DimLayerController/Stack=0 (0xa9d4a800):
>   0:1353)* (animation background stackId=1 (0xa987d800): 0:112)*
>   (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL
>   (0xa9d4bc00): 20:298) (NavigationBar (0xa987c400): 20:46) (Starting
>   br.com.app (0xa986bc00): 20:24)  09-06 15:09:52.164  2829  4059 I
>   WindowManager: Switching to real app window: Window{da0e6a u0
>   br.com.app/br.com.app.MainActivity} 09-06 15:09:52.222  2829  2881 I
>   LaunchCheckinHandler: Displayed br.com.app/.MainActivity,cp,ca,600
>   09-06 15:09:52.223  2829  2881 I ActivityManager: Displayed
>   br.com.app/.MainActivity: +600ms 09-06 15:09:54.942   637   637 D
>   SFPerfTracer:        layers: (5:11) (StatusBar (0xa987ec00): 9:31376)
>   (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (0xa9d49400): 9:20538)* (Sprite
>   (0xa987b000): 0:34)* (DimLayerController/Stack=0 (0xa9d4a800):
>   0:1353)* (animation background stackId=1 (0xa987d800): 0:112)*
>   (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL
>   (0xa9d4bc00): 0:309)- (NavigationBar (0xa987c400): 9:78) (Starting
>   br.com.app (0xa986bc00): 0:45)- (br.com.app/br.com.app.MainActivity
>   (0xa9d48000): 10:30) (br.com.app/br.com.app.MainActivity (0xa81d5000):
>   125:163) (br.com.app/br.com.app.MainActivity (0xa81d6400): 28:45) 
>   09-06 15:10:11.599 19365 19365 E AndroidRuntime: Process: br.com.app,
>   PID: 19365 09-06 15:10:11.599 19365 19365 E AndroidRuntime:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   zzJU()Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzq; in class
>   Lcom/google/firebase/iid/zzq; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.firebase.iid.zzq' appears in
>   /data/app/br.com.app-1/base.apk) 09-06 15:10:11.601  2829  3751 W
>   ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity br.com.app/.MainActivity
>   09-06 15:10:12.110  2829  2848 W ActivityManager: Activity pause
>   timeout for ActivityRecord{6c0658b u0 br.com.app/.MainActivity t98 f}
>   09-06 15:10:13.786  2829  3751 W ActivityManager:   Force finishing
>   activity br.com.app/.MainActivity 09-06 15:10:13.797   637   637 D
>   SFPerfTracer:        layers: (6:11) (StatusBar (0xa987ec00): 0:31453)
>   (com.android.systemui.ImageWallpaper (0xa9d49400): 0:20613) (Sprite
>   (0xa987b000): 0:34)* (DimLayerController/Stack=0 (0xa9d4a800): 0:1362)
>   (animation background stackId=1 (0xa987d800): 0:112)* (NavigationBar
>   (0xa987c400): 0:165) (br.com.app/br.com.app.MainActivity (0xa9d48000):
>   0:39)- (br.com.app/br.com.app.MainActivity (0xa81d5000): 0:165)-
>   (br.com.app/br.com.app.MainActivity (0xa81d6400): 0:122)* (Application
>   Error: br.com.app (0xa9d48000): 3:70)
>   (com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox/com.google.android.launcher.GEL
>   (0xa81d5000): 0:31)  09-06 15:10:13.809  2829  3751 I ActivityManager:
>   Killing 19365:br.com.app/u0a138 (adj 0): crash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema estava acontecendo por conflito entre as libs. A lib `phonegap-plugin-push` estava conflitando com outra lib `cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy`.

No arquivo plugin.xml que é gerado dentro da pasta plugins/seu_pacote vi que que o plugin de location ficava dessa forma:

```
 <framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.+" />
```

A solução foi alterar essa linha, dessa forma:

```
<framework src="com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.1" />
```

Deixei na mesma versão do plugin que foi gerado pelo `phonegap-plugin-push`.

Assuntos relacionados:

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1588

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/1591